# 301 all old pages to new location

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I have a blog that used to be located in a directory on my domain

mydomain.co.uk/Blog

I have now moved the blog to the root

mydomain.co.uk

How do i 301 all of my old pages to the new ones? I have around 500 pages so doing this manually will take forever.

So i want to do
mydomain.co.uk/Blog/page1 to mydomain.co.uk/page1

mydomain.co.uk/Blog/page2 to mydomain.co.uk/page2

mydomain.co.uk/Blog/page3 to mydomain.co.uk/page3

Thanks

Lea

Comment: This doesn't really have  anything to do with WordPress and would be a better fit for the Webmasters stack: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

have you try to make a backup of the old website and upload the backup in the new website, in this case in the main domain.
Normally I use the plugin "wordpress all in one" to do this. I do not know if this is a possibility for you, but should work just fine.
once your website url is mydomain.co.uk/Blog/ the new url will be mydomain.co.uk, and the pages will be in your url/page1

Comment: "...and upload the backup..." - The OP has already moved the website, they just need to implement a redirect. (?)

Comment: if he moved the website the pages should be working normally, in most of cenarios.